# Search array - PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays, search, phpexcel

I'm using `PHPExcel`, I have an multidimensional array called `$sheetData`. I want to be able to search the array for string `D650`.

For example if the string `D650` is in `$sheetData[12][E]` I want it to return `[12][E]`. I can't seem to find a search function for PHPExcel. I've tried the code below but I am only getting one value back I need all the values. If the code isn't the best way to go about this please let me know. Thanks

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

        $letter = "A";

       for($i = 1; $i<= 26; $i++)
       {

            if ($val[$letter] === $id) {
                return $key;
            }

            $letter++;
        }

    }
   return null;
}

$id = searchForId('Denter code here650', $sheetData);
echo $id;
```

Comment: Note that PHPExcel does not provide a search function to search in arrays, nor does it provide a find in worksheet function, but it isn't difficult to implement within your own code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $row => $val) {
        $letter = "A";
        for($i = 1; $i<= 26; $i++) {
            if ($val[$letter] === $id) {
                return '[' . $row .'][' . $letter . ']';
            }
            $letter++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

though it might be more useful returning an array of row and column

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $row => $val) {
        $letter = "A";
        for($i = 1; $i<= 26; $i++) {
            if ($val[$letter] === $id) {
                return array(
                    'row' => $row,
                    'column' => $letter
                );
            }
            $letter++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Return array is just what I needed. How do I echo the array? `$id = searchForId('D650', $sheetData);
echo $id[0];`

Comment: `echo $id['row'];` and `echo $id['column'];` respectively; `echo $id['column'] . ['row'];` to echo both concatenated like an actual Excel cell reference